# Best Possible Way of Writing a CRUD Method in PHP

Tags: php, class, oop

I have tried to right a CRUD Method in PHP for all Database activities , I'm Posting my code below

```
class Database
{

//Connection Variable
public $dbc;


public function __construct()
{
    self::dbconnect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cms_db');
}

public function __destruct()
{
    self::dbclose($this->dbc);
}

//Function to Connect to Database
public function dbconnect($host, $user, $pass, $db)
{
    //Use  Double Quotes in order to pass the value
    $this->dbc = mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass", "$db") or die("Error in DB connection");
    if ($this->dbc) {
        return $this->dbc;
    } else {
        echo 'Cannot Connect to Database,Contact Your Admin';
    }
} //end of Database Connect


//takes a mysql row set and returns an associative array, where the keys
//in the array are the column names in the row set. If singleRow is set to
//true, then it will return a single row instead of an array of rows.
public function processRowSet($rowSet, $singleRow = false)
{
    $resultArray = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowSet)) {
        array_push($resultArray, $row);
    }

    if ($singleRow === true)
        return $resultArray[0];

    return $resultArray;
}


public function queryselect($field, $where, $table)
{
    $selquery = "select $field from $table $where";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $selquery);

    //echo Query If required to check
    echo $selquery;

    //checking for the number of rows and updating it as required
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
        return $this->processRowSet($result, true);
    else
        return $this->processRowSet($result);
} //Input valid


//insert operation

//Inserts a new row into the database.
//takes an array of data, where the keys in the array are the column names
//and the values are the data that will be inserted into those columns.
//$table is the name of the table.
public function insert($data, $table)
{

    $columns = "";
    $values = "";

    foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
        $columns .= ($columns == "") ? "" : ", ";
        $columns .= $column;
        $values .= ($values == "") ? "" : ", ";
        $values .= "'" . $value . "'";
    }

    $sql = "insert into $table ($columns) values ($values)";


    //you can echo and check what exactly is happening thats it. so nice
    //echo $sql;

    $result = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $sql);

    return $result;

    //return the ID of the user in the database.
    //  return mysqli_insert_id();

} //End of Insert Function


//Updates a current row in the database.
//takes an array of data, where the keys in the array are the column names
//and the values are the data that will be inserted into those columns.
//$table is the name of the table and $where is the sql where clause.
public function update($data, $table, $where)
{

    $out = array();
    foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
        array_push($out, "$column='$value'");
    }
    $set = implode(', ', $out);

    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET $set $where";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $sql);

    echo $sql;

    if ($result) {
        return true;
    } //end of valid if
} //end of update


//Deletes a current row in the database.
//$table is the name of the table and $where is the sql where clause.
public function delete($table, $where)
{
    $sql = "DELETE from $table $where";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $sql);

    //Delete Query can be echoed to check 
    //echo $sql;

    if ($result) {
        return true;
    } //end of valid if
} //end of update


//Function to close the Database Connection
public function dbclose($dbc)
{
    mysqli_close($dbc);
} //end of dbclose
} //end of Database class
```

Whether the Crud Method i have written is correct / Best way if not so how it can be done which is the best way to do it..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: yes friends but i wanted to know whether i'm writing it the right way instead of putting it directly into production and finding problems i wanted to know whether it is the right way or not as i'm  new to PHP OOP, The most recurring question for a beginner developer is am i writing it right or not, that's what i want u guys to help me out with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation could differ from one developer to other, as everyone have their own way to interpret things.

But as a good practice, as usually practiced in various frameworks is to make a different class to manage the connection and executing SQL queries.

For e.g. 
You can create a class that handles DB connection, using mysql or mysqli or PDO.

Next create an abstract class that should define the various CRUD operations and calls the DB class for the operation.

Now, you can create as many class, you want extending the base class, and just changing the table name in it.

Comment: The idea of abstract class is good as you say execution of only the required function would be done when you make a class abstract which increases performance as well , and avoids unnecessary execution of other functions i will reorganize my code buddy thank you so much